# Fastest way to load many images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have single page web app that needs to load many images, they're all relatively small(30kb ish) but I have around a thousand of them. Right now im using a hidden div to load all of them when the user hits my website so they are all cached. What is the best way to do this? Currently it's like a thousand GET requests, would it be possible to somehow zip these and unzip them with js? Would it even make a difference to send them all in one GET?

EDIT: 
 Not sure if I was clear or not but this is how i'm currently doing it

```
<div id="hidden-div">
    <img src="assets/blah.jpg">
    <a ton more img tags>
</div>
```

Just wondering if there is a better/faster way to do this?

Comment: How about dial up, dsl, and 1G users? You only want to load everything at once if the user has a fast connection.

Comment: Are you using HTML5? Would you be open to it?

Comment: How you tried something like http://www.infinite-scroll.com/
The page only loads content when the user scrolls down the site. (As on FB newsfeed).

Comment: @j08691 I've never used sprites (or done any game programming) so I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @AnthonyHorne Yes I'm Using HTML5

Comment: @CodeCamper This is just a hobby project, not many people will see it so I'm not really planning for anything other than the connection speed I have right now(which is fast)

Comment: Sprited aren't just for game development. Try Googling CSS sprites and you should learn a bunch about it.

Comment: @Igglyboo Are all images displayed once loaded at document ? Or, displayed incrementally ? Perhaps several options available to utilize to achieve requirement. Can also save reference to each image as data-uri, then `img` could be stored as `text`, or utilize jquery `.load()` http://api.jquery.com/load/ to fetch and load images incrementally, i.e.g, perhaps `<10` per `.load()` call, until all "loaded", into "hidden" `div`, or `document` itself.  The method described at original post appears works, as well

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just "preload" the images so that you can use them later (in your app/page), then you can use the following HTML 5 code:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="http://davidwalsh.name/wp-content/themes/walshbook3/images/sprite.png" />
```

See: Link prefetching is a browser mechanism, which utilizes browser idle time to download or prefetch documents that the user might visit in the near future. A web page provides a set of prefetching hints to the browser, and after the browser is finished loading the page, it begins silently prefetching specified documents and stores them in its cache. When the user visits one of the prefetched documents, it can be served up quickly out of the browser's cache.
URL, then description, then title, keywords.. and finally body.

If for gallery, then @Santosh is correct.  Or http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Infinite-Scroll-Like-Bing-bc05262b